# Adding an argument to Tool function in Langchain agents

Tags: artificial-intelligence, agent, zapier, langchain

i want to create a chat bot that uses a chain to predict which tool should it use for the given query and only add those tools to the agent.
Can anyone tell me how to do this with ZapierNLA. The approach i am following is to get the action ID's of the required tools from ZapierNLA and then use the ZapierNLAWrapper().run function. But this function that takes two arguments (query and id). How can i add the id argument to the Tool function.

```
Tool(
    name=item['name'],
    func=ZapierNLAWrapper().run,
    description=item['description'],
    action_id=item['action_id']
)
```

this is the Tool class

```
class Tool(
    name: str,
    func: (...) -> Any,
    description: str,
    **kwargs: Any
)
```

i should be able to pass the action_id to kwargs but when i run this it gives me an error that
<kbd>pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for Tool
action_id extra fields not permitted (type=value_error.extra)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try a lambda function at the `func` argument?
I am not familiar with ZapierNLAWrapper() so I assume the `run` method consume a dictionary.

```
Tool(
    name=item['name'],
    func=lambda query: ZapierNLAWrapper().run({"action_id": item['action_id'], "query": query}),
    description=item['description'],
)
```